# Преобразовать один XML в другой

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть объект описанный схемой xsd с реквизитами: Ид, Название. Подскажите, как в этой схеме описать тот же объект, только с реквизитами: ИД, Описание? Т.е. можно ли на основании одной схемы xsd преобразовать один объект в другой?
Исходный объект:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CatalogObject.СтатьиЗатрат 
  xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Code>00-000052</Code>
  <Description>Государственная пошлина, кроме судебной</Description>
</CatalogObject.СтатьиЗатрат>
```

На выходе нужен такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
  <category term="StandardODATA.Catalog_СтатьиЗатрат" 
    scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
  <title type="text"/>
  <updated/>
  <author/>
  <summary/>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">           
      <d:Name>Государственная пошлина, кроме судебной</d:Name>
      <d:Code>00-000052</d:Code>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно XSLT-преобразование?

Comment: Я эту тему недавно начал изучать, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, как правильно нужно делать?

Comment: xsd - это технология проверки валидности документа. А xslt - технология преобразования одного xml-документа в другой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cc="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/enterprise/current-config"
  exclude-result-prefixes="cc"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <entry>
      <category term="StandardODATA.Catalog_СтатьиЗатрат" 
        scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
      <title type="text"/>
      <updated/>
      <author/>
      <summary/>
      <content type="application/xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </content>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cc:CatalogObject.СтатьиЗатрат">
    <m:properties 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">           
      <d:Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:Description"/>
      </d:Name>
      <d:Code>
        <xsl:value-of select="cc:Code"/>
      </d:Code>
    </m:properties>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```